# How to tell give an img a fixed, always visible position, fill the screen and have no overflow? (without the background-element))

Tags: html, css

I try to build a webpage, with a screen-filling image. It should be horizontally scrollable and contain other, ~30% wide, images.

I came up with the code down below. Now my first image (bg_full.jpg) is oddly stretched.

Thank you in advance!

If any occur, I am sorry for mistakes in spelling or grammar.

```html
<body>
        <img class="big" src="./bg_full.jpg" alt="Reference image one">
        <img class="small" src="./images/references/reference_1.jpeg" alt="Reference image two">
        <img class="small" src="./images/references/reference_2.jpeg" alt="Reference image three">
        <img class="small" src="./images/references/reference_3.jpeg" alt="Reference image four">

    <!--
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5">
                <img class="grow big" src="./images/references/reference_1.jpeg" alt="Reference image one">
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <img class="grow small" src="./images/references/reference_2.jpeg" alt="Reference image two">
                <img class="grow small" src="./images/references/reference_3.jpeg" alt="Reference image three">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5">
                <img class="grow small" src="./images/references/reference_4.jpeg" alt="Reference image one"><br>
                <img class="grow small" src="./images/references/reference_5.jpeg" alt="Reference image two">
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <img class="grow big" src="./images/references/reference_6.jpeg" alt="Reference image three">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    -->

</body>
```

and

```css
body {
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.big {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.small{
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;} 

.row {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: if your body has width: 500%, do you mean it should be horizontally (e.g. left-right) scrollable? (you said vertically)

Comment: If you want to remove the stretch effekt on your image, you should set either height, or width to `auto`. This means the picture does not stretch but has its fixed height or width, and its corresponding width or height.

Comment: Yes I mean horizontally, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the stretch effekt on your image, you should set either height, or width to auto. This means the picture does not stretch but has its fixed height or width, and its corresponding width or height.

So if you want your width to be 100vw:

```
.style{
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
}
```

or if you want your width to be 100vh:

```
.style{
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
}
```

Overlaying other images on the big image can be done by using `position: absolute;`

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.big {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.small{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <img class="big" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200" alt="Reference image one">
        <img class="small" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/e4000f" alt="Reference image two">

</body>
```

Comment: Hey! First off: thank you for your answer! It seems as if my question is not that clear. I want the 'big' or the first image to fill the screen (100vw) without stretching. Furthermore I do not want the big image to be larger than the screen, so the user can't scroll. And I want to implement, that always, no matter how big/small the screen is ~the middle of the picture is in the window.

Comment: Alright, I will update my answer in a minute. I think i can help you. Just gimme a sec

Comment: @GuardDog I have added a new answer. I now think it is what you wanted to have. I would appreciate if you upvote and accept my answer. I hope I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

So according to your Comment, i hope this will help you:

- If you do not want to stretch the image, you need to set `width: 100vw;` and `height: auto;` this will make sure the picture will resize both axis equally. (or `height: 100vh; width: auto;` respectively)
- Making a Image fill the full screen at all times is a lot easier when using the css property `background-image`, and not an actual image tag inside your html.
- by setting `background-size: cover` you are making sure, that the aspect ratio of the picture stays as is. It will try to make the picture as small as possible, while trying to fully fill the background positioning area.
- by setting background-position: 50% 50% you make sure, that the middle of the picture will always be in the middle of your container div.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.wrapper{
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
max-height: 100vh;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/200x200");
background-size: cover;
}

.big {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
}

.small{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
        <img class="small" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/e4000f" alt="Reference image two">
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: thanks so far! The background is working like a charm, but I am wondering how to horizontally scroll now? Or maybe implement some JS to click a button to change the background? Thank you for your time, I appreciate this! Unfortunatly my Upvotes are not displayed, since I got >15 Reputation :(

Comment: @GuardDog do you mean something like a slideshow?  like this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/ ?

Comment: something like this but w/o bootstrap. I actually would like not to have to click arrows but instead scroll down and the images appear in x-direction